# How can i simply used progress view in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I am trying to save image to the photos album from my app using the following code:

```
 -(void)download:(UIButton *)downloadbtn{

    j=320*downloadbtn.tag;

    selectedIndex=downloadbtn.tag;

    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[live_god_img objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]]];

    UIImage*img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, nil, nil);

    UIAlertView*alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success..!" message:@"Image Saved to the Photos" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

When the image is saved to the photos album, an alert view will be shown, but I would like to show a progress view while image is being saved to the album. I do not know how to use `UIProgressView`. How do I do it?

Comment: You cannot unless your download operation is asynchronous. As your code is currently written (synchronously), there's no way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this tutorial [first](http://www.makemegeek.com/uiprogressview-example-ios/)

You can try like  this in your method.

```
- (IBAction)startProgress:(id)sender
    {
     progressValue = 0.0f;
     [self increaseProgressValue];
   }

-(void)increaseProgressValue
   {
   if(progressView.progress<1)
      {
    progressValue = progressValue+0.1;
    progressView.progress = progressValue;

   [self performSelector:@selector(increaseProgressValue) withObject:self afterDelay:0.2];
     }
  }
```

Comment: I agree with you @LittleBobbyTables . I was thinking in aspect of the person who asked the question but not the other stack flow users. I will provide the necessary info and will update the answer. :)